# How to disable Web Interface?

Tags: arangodb

How do I initialize arango so that the web interface does not run? I have looked through the documentation and the --help options and haven't found the proper configuration option.

Answer (score 1):

You can not disable the web interface. And there would be no gain by doing so. This is because all communication by drivers is done over the same http routes that the web-ui uses. So if it was disabled people could still use curl or drivers to access the database which is anyway much more likely in an automated attack.

Make sure that you have set passwords and **disable-authentication = false** furthermore you should use https endpoints to ensure that no plaintext passwords can be intercepted.